# How to generate a random pattern of *&# in PHP

Tags: php, logic

Hello there i am making a program which will let me help generate a random string with a specified limit and random strings of `*&#` but then the combination of `*&#` should not repeat.

Ex: if I input 3 then the O/P should be

```
#**
**#
**#
```

It should generate a random string of length 3 up to 3 rows with different patterns also the pattern should not repeat. I am using the below code but not able to attain it.

```
$n = 3;
for($i = 0; $i < n; $i++)
  {
     for($j=0;$j<=$n;j++)
       {
          echo "*#";
       }
     echo "<br />";
  }
```

But I am not able to generate the output, where is my logic failing?

Comment: Your echoing the same thing each iteration

Comment: I have updated the code up to my logic, still its not working

Comment: Your question as it is written is unclear.  You say the rows should be unique but you expect `#**` `**#` `**#`.  Please update your question so that future readers are not confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure the same pattern doesn't show up more than once you'll have to keep a record of the generated strings. In the most basic form it could look like this:

```
public function generate() {
    $amount = 3;  // The amount of strings you want.
    $generated_strings = []; // Keep a record of the generated strings.
    do {
        $random = $this->generateRandomString(); // Generate a random string
        if(!in_array($random, $generated_strings)) { // Keep the record if its not already present.
            $generated_strings[] = $random;
        }
    } while(sizeof($generated_strings) !== $amount); // Repeat this process until you have three strings.

    print_r($generated_strings);
}


public function generateRandomString($length = 3) {
    $characters = '*&#';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly as i wanted but what was the logic behind it?

Comment: I've added (some of) the explanations in `//` behing the lines. Is there a specific part you can't follow?

Comment: Ummm well yes, i got the code explanation where can I find some more challenging codes like this to keep my logic brushed up?

Comment: Ehh, just try googling for exercises/online courses/books/etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop and array unique to do this.
I first have an array with possible chars.
Then I loop until result array is desired lenght.
I use array unique to remove any duplicates inside the loop.
I use rand(0,2) to "select" a random character from possible characters array.

```
$arr = ["*", "&", "#"];
$res = array();

$n =7;

While(count($res) != $n){
    $temp="";
    For($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
         $temp .= $arr[Rand(0,count($arr)-1)];
    }
    $res[] = $temp;
    $res = array_unique($res);
}

Var_dump($res);
```

https://3v4l.org/Ko4Wd

Updated with out of scope details not clearly specified by OP.

Comment: If i enter 7 then the row should be 7 as well as the length of generated string should be 7

Comment: You have not said that. Nowhere in your question does it say the length of string. Your question says *It should generate a random string of length 3* not that it's dependant of the $n value @Akshay

Comment: Please re-read the question again the 3 is a variable and please remove the down vote as i have mentioned it clearly

Comment: @Akshay you can remove your downvote now, I have updated the code

Comment: Also remove the downvote you have given to the question and delete this comment

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily the most optimized algorithm but it should work.

I am using a string generator, somewhat random, combining the chars you have provided. The second part is filling the output array with generated strings that are not already present.

```
<?php

function randomize($n) {
  $s = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    $s. = (rand(0, 10) < 5 ? '*' : '#');
  }
  return $s;
}


$n = 3;
$output = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
  $tmp = randomize($n);
  while (in_array($tmp, $output)) {
    $tmp = randomize($n);
  }
  $output[] = $tmp;
}
print_r($output);
```

[Visible here](https://3v4l.org/gWJHf)

Comment: Your code doesn't run. A $ is missing and the dot on line 4 is misplaced

Comment: @mickmackusa the code is prey self explanatory but I will try to add a description of what's happening :)